# Discrepancy in data for the same landing page

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I used PageSpeed Insights to analyze the same landing page few times, separated with only few seconds or minutes but every time I am getting a totally different result. It can be a huge discrepancy from 23 score performance to 56 or even 66 performance (please see screenshot attached). Could you please tell me how come there is this huge discrepancy ?

Thank you

[data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7sDm.png)

[data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1nL3.png)

Comment: screenshots are the same, could you fix

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.